# jQuery form validation not detecting elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am adding inputs to my form using jquery's `appendTo()`, but I have a problem.
When I am adding these inputs, jQuery Validation can't detect them.

I created a function that iterates over these inputs and adds the rules.

```
$("input[name^=cmp_]").each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add", {
                    minlength: 50,
                    required: true,
                    digits: true

                });
            });
```

New inputs also have unique names `cmp_phone1`, `cmp_phone2`, `cmp_phone3`, `cmp_phone4`.

My question is how to validate the form after changing it?

Comment: **You must show enough code to reproduce the issue, because [your posted code is working**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8dDS/).  Show the rest of your jQuery along with the HTML markup required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what are you doing.

I suppose you are iterating over the fields on page load, and not applying these rules after the addition. You should move the function from `.each()` to the parent scope, and `.apply` it after the addition on the element (if you want to use `this`).
In such case, I suggest you should just use the `$(el)` instead, and pass it in first parameter. `.each()` automatically does that too. No need for `.apply`, just call it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name^="cmp_"]').each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add", {
                    minlength: 50,
                    required: true,
                    digits: true

                });
            });
```

try this.

Comment: don't see any difference

Comment: try putting alert
`$('input[name^="cmp_"]').each(function() {
               var Value2 = this.id;
alert(Value2);
            });`

Comment: have try catch and see if any error popups, try to use firebug and debug your code. this will help you to rectify the problem ASAP. 

example given above should work. there is some other issues.

Comment: Your code is effectively identical to the OP's.  Yes, I see you added more quotes, but those aren't always necessary.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/XmuFm/